# Cropping rectangle from Image using Opencv python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, crop

Im trying to crop rectangle image from screenshot, background for image must be white, Im ending up having black,How can I change that? I want to make histogtam of rgb for the  final image and It seems plotting only    vertical line on zero, Any kind of help is very important! here is my code:

```
import cv2 
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg

image = cv2.imread(filename = "Screenshot from 2019-11-08 22-02-27.png")
mask = np.zeros(shape = image.shape, dtype = "uint8")
cv2.rectangle(img = mask, 
    pt1 = (0, 185), pt2 = (1900, 773), 
    color = (255, 255, 255), 
    thickness = -1)



maskedImg = cv2.bitwise_and(src1 = image, src2 = mask)
cv2.imwrite("processed.png", maskedImg)
plt.imshow(maskedImg)
plt.show()


plt.hist(maskedImg.ravel(),256,[0,256]); plt.show()
```

Comment: to crop use `cropped_image = image[y1:y2,x1:x2]`

Answer (score 0):

```html
import cv2 
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg

image = cv2.imread(filename = "1.png")
mask = np.zeros(shape = image.shape, dtype = "uint8")
cv2.rectangle(img = mask, 
    pt1 = (0, 185), pt2 = (1900, 773), 
    color = (255, 255, 255), 
    thickness = -1)
maskedImg = cv2.bitwise_and(src1 = image, src2 = mask)
maskedImg[np.where((maskedImg==[0,0,0]).all(axis=2))] = [255,255,255]

cv2.imwrite("processed.png", maskedImg)
plt.imshow(maskedImg)
plt.show()
```

Convert the black pixel present in the image into white pixel

Original image
[image]

Crop Image
[image]

[image]

```html
color = ('b','g','r')
for i,col in enumerate(color):
    histr = cv2.calcHist([maskedImg],[i],None,[256],[0,256])
    plt.plot(histr,color = col)
    plt.xlim([0,256])
plt.show()
```

Comment: Hello! @Sebin Sunny thank u for the replay! iI run the code as u wrtie and for the histogram it is blank :( also If rectangle is black and I want it in the white background it gets white also

Comment: hist = cv2.calcHist([maskedImg],[0],None,[256],[0,256])
plt.hist(hist.ravel(),256,[0,256])
plt.title('Histogram for the picture') code will plot the histogram

Comment: I know that part is responsible for plotting, but It doesnt drow anything when I run the code , any idea how to do it ?

Comment: this is my new code and the plotting part doesnt work I dont know :(

Comment: plotting is working with the above code I have shared

Comment: I tried your code and mine and there was the same result, hovewer when I tried your picture it was working! do u have any suggestion how can I make it work with the picture I want? sorry I m asking u a lot, its my first time doing it and its very essential, thanks for your help!

Comment: could you please send me the url of the image

Comment: https://ibb.co/jgvpdbg  this is what I want just a schreenshot of airbnb stay section

Comment: color = ('b','g','r')
for i,col in enumerate(color):
    histr = cv2.calcHist([maskedImg],[i],None,[256],[0,256])
    plt.plot(histr,color = col)
    plt.xlim([0,256])
plt.show()